# How to change Higchart parameter Value depends on My dataTable Column Filter

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts, datatable

I Have Used Column Filter for Every Column in dataTable And Also used Highcharts for dataTable Value , My question is Highchart dynamicaly change depends on Datatable filtering data Is it Possible? How to I implement?

Comment: Anything is possible :) But we need a lot more detail and preferably a live example or fiddle of your code.

Comment: Highcharts won't dynamically change anything for you. There is [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series) to call after updates etc. And how to implement it? Well, SO is not a place to write whole guide and/or whole project for you, so first you need to start and ask more detailed question.